# Insert a number before a given number in a linked list

Tags: matlab, linked-list, insert

I'm doing an introduction course in programing in matlab and python and I have only been coding for a short time, so I'm still on the basics. 
In the problem that I'm trying to solve, we have been given a code that creates a linked list by the teacher.

```
    classdef Elem < handle
    %Elem A class realising a linked list. 

    properties
      data
      next = Elem.empty
    end

    methods

    function node = Elem(value)
         if (nargin > 0)
            node.data = value;
         end
    end

    function obj = insert(obj, value)       
        if(isempty(obj.next))
            obj.next = Elem(value);
        else
           obj.next.insert(value); 
        end
    end

    %  More methods go here

    end
end
```

One of the questions is then to make a code that can insert a number before a number in the linked list.
To do this I have made this code.

```
   function newlist=InsertBefore(list,newdata,dataBefore)
        if ~isempty(list)
            if list.data==dataBefore
                newlist = Elem(newdata);
                newlist.next = list;
            elseif list.next.data==dataBefore
                newlist=list;
                newelem = Elem(newdata);
                newelem.next = list.next;
                newlist.next = newelem;
            else
                InsertBefore(list.next,newdata,dataBefore)
            end
        end
    end
```

If I then write

```
linkedlist2=InsertBefore(LinkedList,4,12)
```

the function makes a new list with 4 in front of the 12 which is the first number in the list. so the "If" part of the code works fine. if I try doing the same thing with a number in the middle of the list it says.

```
Output argument "newlist" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to "InsertBefore".
```

I have tried many things but nothing has really worked perfect yet, so your help is much appreciated

Thanks

Lasse

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED
Had to have
    else
    **newlist =** InsertBefore(list.next,newdata,dataBefore)